# how can i add a c++ function for javascript to call in Chromium 88

Tags: c++, chromium, v8

The web page can call the c++ funtion to send infomation to my customized browser base on Chromium 88.
Which file should edit in Chromium 88?

updated on 2020.11.27

I want to add a function in window.extenal, how should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in `bootstrapper.cc`.

That said, please keep in mind:

- maintaining a Chromium fork is *a lot* of work, because Chromium changes very fast
- using an outdated browser is highly dangerous, so if you do create a fork, you really have to maintain it
- if you can't commit to maintaining your fork, then figuring out how to do such modifications in the first place is probably not a good investment of your time.

(I realize that that probably isn't what you wanted to hear; sorry about that. I'm just trying to help you avoid regretting earlier decisions later on. If you have considered these points before, then never mind, carry on.)

Comment: I have written a simple function in bootstrapper.cc 
int helloworld(){
  return 0;
}
I am not able to get it executed in chrome.